# Javascript floating point number addition different outputs

Tags: javascript

Why this will not give the results as expected?

```
console.log(0.2+0.1); // gives 0.30000000000000004 
console.log(0.2+0.3); // gives 0.5
console.log(0.2+0.5); // gives 0.7
console.log(0.2+0.4); // gives 0.6000000000000001
```

Why the `first` and `last` will not give the results as expected?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1

Comment: That's a known problem. Try to use `.toPrecision()` or `.toFixed()`

Comment: That's not a problem, but Floating-Point Arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s because `JavaScript` used the `IEEE Standard` for `Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic`.

All `floating point math` is like this and is based on the `IEEE 754 standard`. JavaScript uses `64-bit floating point representation`, which is the same as Java's `double`.

Can be possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

Try `.toFixed()` .This method formats a number with a specific number of digits to the right of the decimal.

```
console.log((0.2 + 0.1).toFixed(1)); // gives 0.3
console.log((0.2 + 0.3).toFixed(1)); // gives 0.5
console.log((0.2 + 0.5).toFixed(1)); // gives 0.7
console.log((0.2 + 0.4).toFixed(1)); // gives 0.6
```

Comment: Thanks Devang, I know about `toFixed` method. I wanted to know what is the reason behind this `unexpected result`.